Multiple node selection - no way to specify in package.json if command is part of multiple node selection
I have enabled multiple node selection of treeview. On right click of the node, they display different commands as per context value defined in package.json.
I did not find way to set context value in package.json to know if command is part of multiple node selection.
e.g. let's assume, there are three nodes N1, N2 and N3.
N1 can have three commands C1, C2 and C3 ,
N2 can have two commands C1 and C4 and
N3 can have two commands C3 and C4.
In above case C1 command can be possible on two nodes (N1 and N2) and C4 on Two nodes (N2 and N3) while C3 is unique to N1
Since C1 command and C4 command can be possible on multiple nodes so I need to know how to specify this in package. Json?
